# How do I go about implementing a static method which references a parent object defined in the main?

Tags: java, class, methods, static

I am trying to create a model for a school time table in Java where a session on the timetable is made up of a period(time) and a subject eg. english, maths etc. I am wanting to load this information into the model using CSV Files (I know really inefficient).

Currently, I have coded out the classes for Periods and subjects with a static method created to load from a file into an array. I am just a little bit stuck with loading the subjects in from a CSV file when it needs to access the values already stored with in the model.

```java
class TimetableModel { 
   List<Period> periods;
   List<Subject> subjects; 

   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      TimetableModel model = new TimeTable(model);
      model.periods = Period.fromCSV("periods.csv");
      model.subjects = Subject.fromCSV("subjects.csv");

   }
}
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. You put up some code (that wont compile because you omitted a trailing " on the subjects.csv string literal), some requirements ... but not what your question is?!

Comment: And unrelated: *using CSV Files (I know really inefficient)* What makes you think so? Don't worry about efficiency at this point. Make sure you understand what you are doing, and that your code does what you want it to do. Having your data in "easy to modify" CSV style files is actually a pretty good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I go about implementing a static method which references a parent object defined in the main?

You can pass the parent object as a parameter to the static (or instance) method.

Better idea: you don't define (declare) the parent object in `main`.  Instead, put your code into instance methods, and declare the parent object as an instance field so that all of the instance methods for the class can use it.

Comment: Would it be possible get some example code for defining it is a instance field.

Comment: See saidaspen's answer.  It is declaring and using instance fields.  Alternatively, this is covered in any half-decent Java tutorial or textbook ...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not putting the logic in the main method. Instead, put your logic inside of a method of the model.

This is a common way of doing it:

```
class TimetableModel {
    List<Period> periods;
    List<Subject> subjects;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimetableModel().init();
    }

    private void init() { 
        TimetableModel model = new TimeTable(model);
        model.periods = Period.fromCSV("periods.csv");
        model.subjects = Subject.fromCSV("subjects.csv");
    }
```

I suggest you go read up on what the `static` keyword means.
For example (first hit on when I goolged):
[Understanding Static in Java](https://blog.jbaysolutions.com/2016/08/16/understanding-static-in-java/)